# Create Interactive Dialog Box based on the User input using Sitecore Powershell

Tags: sxa, powershell

I want to create an interactive dialog using `PowerShell script`.

I have multiple sites under the same `Tenant` if I select any site node in field 1, then field 2 root node should be changed to that site's Data folder. Then the user can select any item under the Data folder.

**Scenario:**

Tenant A

- SiteA

  - SiteA/Data/Form Folder
- SiteB

  - SiteB/Data/Form Folder

If user select SiteA in the Field 1, then Field 2 should show SiteA/Data/Form Folder as its starting node.

**Edit:**

```
$dialog = Read-Variable -Parameters `
    @{ Name = "language"; Title = "Select Language"; Source="DataSource=/sitecore/system/languages"; Editor="droplist"},
    @{ Name = "siteNode"; Title = "Select Site"; Source="DataSource=/sitecore/content/Sitecore902&DatabaseName=master&IncludeTemplatesForDisplay=Site"; editor="droplist"} `
    -Description "This module is used to import Data." `
    -Width 400 -Height 200 `
    -Title "Import Utility" `
    -OkButtonName "Select" `
    -CancelButtonName "Cancel"

if ($dialog -ne "ok") 
{
    Exit
}

$dialog1 = Read-Variable -Parameters `
    @{ Name = "itemPath"; Title = "Select Location"; Root=$siteNode.Paths.FullPath + "/Data/POIs"; Editor="item"} `
    -Description "This module is used to import Data." `
    -Width 400 -Height 200 `
    -Title "Import Utility" `
    -OkButtonName "Import" `
    -CancelButtonName "Cancel"

if ($dialog1 -ne "ok") 
{
    Exit
}
```

In here, I am using two `Read-Variable`. As you can see the value of `siteNode` is being used in `itemPath`. I want all the selections in one dialog box, and the functionality should remain the same. Right now, if I add `itemPath` to the `$dialog`, it is not working as expected.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you checked out the examples under the Getting Started module? There is an example "Kitchen Sink" script that shows how to work with Read-Variable.

Comment: Yes, I checked that example, I also created a workaround, but I need all the fields in the same dialog box. Please have a look at the edit I made to the question.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to set the second field from the value selected in the first, within a single dialogue. I'm not aware of any way to do this, or even of any events that you could use within a dialogue to build the functionality yourself.

Comment: @JamesWalford yes initially I was looking for the same functionality as you stated. But I couldn't able to find anything on that. So, I opted to go with 2 dialog boxes as you can see in the Edit part of the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have issues with syntax in your second dialogue, essentially you weren't concatenating the string like you thought you were. This should work.

```
$dialog1 = Read-Variable -Parameters `
    @{ Name = "itemPath"; Title = "Select Location"; Root="$($siteNode.Paths.FullPath)/Data/POIs"; Editor="item"} `
    -Description "This module is used to import Data." `
    -Width 400 -Height 200 `
    -Title "Import Utility" `
    -OkButtonName "Import" `
    -CancelButtonName "Cancel"
```

Let's build up what's happening here in stages:

Root is expecting a string, so we start with `Root=""`
You want to embed a variable in this string, so you add your `$sitenode`

```
Root="$siteNode.Paths.FullPath"
```

But PowerShell is then interpreting the object properties as a literal string. It calls `object.ToString()` on the `$siteNode` variable itself. The actual content of the string Root is now: "Sitecore.Data.Items.Item.Paths.FullPath"

So you need to wrap anything you need evaluated (properties, methods) in `$()`

```
Root="$($siteNode.Paths.FullPath)"
```

Now the $siteNode properties/methods are evaluated instead of being embedded into the string as string literals - the Root string is the full path of your siteNode item.

But you want to specify a specific path beneath the siteNode path, so you add your relative path directly to the string:

```
Root="$($siteNode.Paths.FullPath)/Data/POIs"
```